# Did defeated countries pay their war bonds?

Tags: world-war-two, war, economy, finance, political-economy

[This related question approaches how beneficial war bonds were to US during WWII](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/767/how-beneficial-were-war-bonds-to-the-us-during-wwii).
I would like to know what happen with war bonds when a country is defeated.

What did happen in similar experiences?

What would have happened with US war bonds if it had lost any of the world wars?

Comment: German ww1 war bonds became pretty ,such worthless after the hyper inflation of the early 1920s.

Comment: This would certainly depend on the country and war. Japan paid off its (domestic, at least) WW2 war bonds (but after using inflation to devalue them).

Comment: We can't really answer the specifics of the last question; since the US/Allies did not lose WWII, we'll never know.

Comment: France was in August 1914 paying about 34% of its national revenue to service war debt accumulated during the 19th century, including military costs and *reparations* from its loss in the 1870 Franco-Prussian War. http://encyclopedia.1914-1918-online.net/article/war_finance_france